# I am getting weird output

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So, I am trying to retrieve data from my mysql database after a user registers or logins. The thing is that it somehow retrieves the letter "u" and that's weird, because there is no place that contains the letter "u".

This is the result I am getting as of now 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSv2L.jpg

index.php(where user registers or logs in)

```
<?php include('server.php') ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>PwettyKittyPincesa</title>

  <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script>
      function start(){
        closeForm();
        closeRegForm();
      }

      function openForm() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
        closeRegForm();
      }

      function closeForm() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
      }

      function openRegForm() {
        document.getElementById("myRegForm").style.display = "block";
        closeForm();
      }

      function closeRegForm() {
        document.getElementById("myRegForm").style.display = "none";
      }
      </script>

</head>
<body onload="start()">
  <nav>
      <button class="button" type="submit" onclick="openForm()">Влез</button>
      <button class="buttonReg" type="submit" onclick="openRegForm()">Регистрирай се</button>
      <img src="Logo4.png" class="Logo" alt="Logo">
  </nav>

  <div class="form-popupRegister" id="myRegForm">
    <form method="post" action="server.php" class="form-containerReg">

        <h1>Регистрирация</h1>

        <label for="username"><b>Име</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Въведете името на лейдито" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">


        <label for="email"><b>Е-майл</b></label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Въведете e-mail" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">


        <label for="password_1"><b>Парола</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Въведете парола" name="password_1">


        <label for="password_2"><b>Повторете Парола</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Въведете парола повторно" name="password_2">


        <button type="submit" class="btnReg" name="reg_user">Register</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-cancelReg" onclick="closeRegForm()">Close</button>
    </form>
</div>

  <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
    <form method="post" action="server.php" class="form-container">

        <h1>Влизане</h1>

            <label for="username"><b>Име</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">

            <label for="password"><b>Парола</b></label>
            <input type="password" name="password">

            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="login_user">Login</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn-cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index2.php(where the data should be output)

```
<?php include('server.php') ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>PwettyKittyPincesa</title>

  <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script>
    function getUserStats(){
        <?php
            $queryThree = "SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE ID='$idQuery' ";
            $userStats = mysqli_query($db,$queryThree);
            $userStatsTwo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userStats);
        ?>
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="getUserStats()">
    <div class="navWrapper">
        <div class="statistics">
            <div class="profilePicture" name="profilePicture">
                <label class="profilePictureLabel" for="profilePicture"><b><?php echo userStatsTwo['username']; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="money" name="money">
                <label class="rubyLabel" for="ruby"><b><?php echo userStatsTwo['money']; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="diamond" name="diamond">
                <label class="diamondLabel" for="diamond"><b><?php echo userStatsTwo['diamonds']; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="ruby" name="ruby">
                <label class="rubyLabel" for="ruby"><b><?php echo userStatsTwo['ruby']; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="level" name="level">
                <label class="levelLabel" for="level"><b>Level:<?php echo userStatsTwo['level']; ?></b></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

server.php(where the data is being processed)

```
<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$idQuery = "";
$errors = array(); 


// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'id9159890_uregisterdb', 'censored', 'id9159890_registerdb');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
  // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
  if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
  }

  // first check the database to make sure 
  // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }

    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
  }

  // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

    $query = "INSERT INTO `register` (username, password, email, money, ruby, diamonds, levelpoints, level)
    VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $idQuery = "SELECT ID FROM `register` WHERE username='$username'";
    mysqli_query($db, $idQuery);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $idQuery;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: index2.php');
  }
}


// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE username='$username'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: index2.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }
}

  ?>
```

The results that I should be getting are(from top to bottom and left to right)
Username, Level, Money, Diamond, Ruby and their values should respectively be Username, 0, 0, 0, 0.

I've tried everything and nothing changes, I've re-constructed my code twice and it still outputs only that and nothing else.

Comment: `$idQuery` where u define this?

Comment: Can you show the row for that user in your database?

Comment: u have typoSS in your code `<?php echo userStatsTwo['username']; ?>` where is the `$` sign

Comment: At the beginning of the server.php file.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use Javascript and PHP interchangeably.  They don't work like that.

Comment: second, if `'id9159890_uregisterdb', 'censored', 'id9159890_registerdb'` credentials belongs to LIVE server, please change this.

Comment: @aynber https://imgur.com/P64hqvI

Comment: my dear friend, u have TYPO here `<?php echo userStatsTwo['money']; ?>
            <?php echo userStatsTwo['diamonds']; ?>
            <?php echo userStatsTwo['ruby']; ?>
            <?php echo userStatsTwo['level']; ?>`

Comment: @devpro
I added $ sign in front of the userStatsTwo and now the u disappeared, but no other output replaced its place, so that must not be the issue.

Comment: @XanderNedelchev Refer back to the very first comment.

Comment: @PatrickQ it is defined at the beginning of the server.php file.

Comment: for suppose its defined try this `echo "SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE ID='$idQuery' ";` and share the result

Comment: second, also share the result of `print_r($userStatsTwo);`

Comment: @XanderNedelchev Ignore now-deleted comment, I see now that it is in the question

Comment: `$idQuery = "SELECT ID FROM \`register\` WHERE username='$username'";`  You are defining `$idQuery` not as an ID, but as a string.

Comment: @PatrickQ his end query looks like `SELECT * FROM register` WHERE ID= 'SELECT ID FROM `register` WHERE username='somename''` if success

Comment: i think `$idQuery` is empty .... maybe... if he show the result of `echo "SELECT * FROM register` WHERE ID='$idQuery' ";`` then all issues will be solved.. i hope

Comment: `$idQuery` is either empty(depending on the result of `if (count($errors) == 0) {`) or is a string value that I guarantee is _not_ going to match any ID.  As a result, no rows are going to be returned, which is why nothing is being output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue here in your code:

```
$idQuery = "SELECT ID FROM `register` WHERE username='$username'";
mysqli_query($db, $idQuery);
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['userid'] = $idQuery;
```

As i mentioned in my comment, check what are you getting in `echo "SELECT * FROM register WHERE ID='$idQuery' ";` you definitely getting this kind of result:

```
SELECT * FROM register` WHERE ID= 'SELECT ID FROM `register` WHERE username='somename''
```

For sub query, remove quotes around your variable from:

```
"SELECT * FROM register` WHERE ID='$idQuery' ";
```

should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM register` WHERE ID = $idQuery";
```

Note that, this is success case, as you show your result here `https://imgur.com/P64hqvI`, your query is working fine..

You also need to use some protection for `$idQuery` if `$idQuery == ''` then your you can't get any result also.

*As @patrick-q mentioned, use session to store `username` or `ID` instead of saving a full query.*

Second, you code is wide open for SQL injection, for preventing, use PDO.

Some helpful links:

[Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Or just `SELECT *` in the first query and store the results to session.  No point of issuing multiple queries to the same table for the same row.

Comment: @PatrickQ: agreed, must need to optimize code, when everything available, no need to use things twice.